# How do I install amdgpu-dkms in Unbuntu-22?

Tags: drivers, apt, compiling

When installing using the apparently "good" `amdgpu-install` command,

```
# amdgpu-install version
# amdgpu-install_22.20.50200-1_all.deb
# cut date: 2023-9-13
# today: 2023-99-20

# allegedly good command 1
amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics

# allegedly good command 2
amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics --vulkan=amdvlk --opencl=rocr
```

I get a failure building or installing `amdgpu-dkms`.  When building/installing via `amdgpu-install`, I get more information from a makefile log, but `apt-get install amdgpu-dkms` yields an error as well:

```
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-33-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  You are using:           gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/Makefile:16: *** dma_resv->seq is missing., exit....  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:2026: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-33-generic'

# KEY LINE
dma_resv->seq is missing., exit....  Stop.
```

I suppose `dma_resv` is missing. The next thing I tried was installing it via apt-get:

```
apt-get install amdgpu-dkms
```

Which fails as well.

Is there anyone who has successfully run `amdgpu-dkms` on Ubuntu-22?

### UPDATES

I am continuing to troubleshoot this. Installing a normal version of `dkms` does not provide what AMD requires. Instead, AMD ships with its own broken dkms automake package at:

```
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/source/amd/dkms
```

And a run of `configure` yields a deeper error:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-realtime
...
# in amd/.../dkms
sudo ./configure

# I was able to move forward on this by installing the linux headers above
# but only 2 lines forward. The UTS_RELEASE definition is still missing. 
# As far as I can tell, my kernel is *not* the realtime kernel, so
# I probably need to install the realtime kernel. 

checking kernel source directory... /usr/src/linux-realtime-headers-5.15.0-1032
checking kernel build directory... /usr/src/linux-realtime-headers-5.15.0-1032
checking kernel source version... Not found
configure: error: *** Cannot find UTS_RELEASE definition.
```

-- I think whoever was dev'ing the package optimized for the ubuntu `realtime` kernel, which is available in the pro version.  I don't have that right now, but I think it might be a pre-requisite for the AMD GPU install on the new `2023-9-13` build of the `amdgpu-install...deb`.